# Grub2 unable to boot encrypted root

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, dm-crypt

I'm using ArchLinux, I followed their tutorial on encrypting your root filesystem:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Using_DM-Crypt

But I cannot get grub to boot the encrypted partition.

My grub file looks like this:

```
root (hd0,2)
kernel /vmlinuz-linux cryptdevice=/dev/sda4:root root=/dev/mapper/root ro
initramfs /intiramfs-linux.img
```

I've tried editing this to everything I could think of, and everything I could find online, but nothing will boot. It always gives me this error:

```
ERROR: device '/dev/mapper/root' not found. Skipping fsck.
ERROR: unable to find root device '/dev/mapper/root'.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't look like a Grub2 configuration file, looks like plain Grub.

Comment: This isn't a grub issue per se; it is your initramfs that does not seem to understand how to open the encrypted volume.

Comment: Did you add the "encrypt" hook to /etc/mkinitcpio.conf and rebuilt your initramfs?

Answer (score 2):

As [Wieland said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42587/grub2-unable-to-boot-encrypted-root#comment58571_42587), you must inform a ramfs image to decrypt the root partition.

Which means to add the **encrypt** hook to **/etc/mkinitcpio.conf** before **filesystems** hook by changing this line (this should be default setting in vanilla Arch installation):

```
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

to this:

```
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block encrypt filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

*(For more details, see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Configuring_mkinitcpio)*

And then recompile ramfs image with following command (in arch-chroot with **/boot** mounted):

```
# mkinitcpio -p linux
```

*(Again, for more details, see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mkinitcpio#Image_creation_and_activation)*