# Grub configuration is damaged: error device /dev/mapper/luks-03xxxxxx not found

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, grub, manjaro

When running an Manjaro (Arch) upgrade, I somehow broke my system.
I managed to fix a bit of it, but not everything.
When starting the computer, I see something like this:

```
error device /dev/mapper/luks-03xxxxxx not found
skipping fsck
mount /new_root no filesystem type specified
```

When I mount my encrypted filesystem with the help of an ISO USB Stick and I make an `lsblk -f`
I see my decrypted device like this:

```
sda                                                                         
└─sda1
     crypto 1           a03f75ee-2af7-40f4-bba5-5d9d241afc73                
  └─luks-a03f75ee-2af7-40f4-bba5-5d9d241afc73
     ext4   1.0         a9b268a6-f403-4113-80a7-67f9650fc376  107.3G    46% /run/media
```

I also made a new Grub [as mentioned in the Manjaro wiki.](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Restore_the_GRUB_Bootloader)

still the same error.

I also found this [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507857/119937) but the part with `# mount /dev/MyVolGroup/root /mnt` is not working at all for me.

When I enter the Grub with `E` on startup, I can change the boot params.
It looks like this for me:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Manjaro Linux' --class manjaro --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-a9b268a6-f403-4113-80a7-67f9650fc376' {
    savedefault
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod cryptodisk
    insmod luks
    insmod gcry_rijndael
    insmod gcry_rijndael
    insmod gcry_sha256
    insmod ext2
    cryptomount -u a03f75ee2af740f4bba55d9d241afc73
    set root='cryptouuid/a03f75ee2af740f4bba55d9d241afc73'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='cryptouuid/a03f75ee2af740f4bba55d9d241afc73'  a9b268a6-f403-4113-80a7-67f9650fc376
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a9b268a6-f403-4113-80a7-67f9650fc376
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4-x86_64 root=UUID=a9b268a6-f403-4113-80a7-67f9650fc376 rw  quiet cryptdevice=UUID=a03f75ee-2af7-40f4-bba5-5d9d241afc73:luks-a03f75ee-2af7-40f4-bba5-5d9d241afc73 root=/dev/mapper/luks-a03f75ee-2af7-40f4-bba5-5d9d241afc73 resume=/dev/mapper/luks-a03f75ee-2af7-40f4-bba5-5d9d241afc73 apparmor=1 security=apparmor udev.log_priority=3
    initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-5.4-x86_64.img
}
```

I'm thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it.

what I did:

I fixed it.
after everything I have done, I used this [Grub2 unable to boot encrypted root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42587/grub2-unable-to-boot-encrypted-root)

change from:

```
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

to

```
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block encrypt filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

after this use `mkinitcpio -p linux`

after this I reinstalled grub again, and somehow it works.
I have now to answer 2 times the password for decryption, but now it works.